# UploadedFile getPathname is empty

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, file-upload

After deployed my Laravel code on Ubuntu server I have following function returning empty string:

```
$package = $request->file('file');
dd($package->getPathname());
```

while locally (Windows) it is working and on other hosting (Ubuntu too) it is working too.
What could be the reason for that?

Thank you!

Comment: check if the web user on the ubuntu has access to write the temp upload file directory

Comment: that was the reason

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas As the asker commented your comment was the reason, you should write your comment as an answer.

Comment: hope it helps others, as this is otherwise a pretty ancient question.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the web user that the php is running on being denied the access to the temp directory used to store the uploaded files.

You can check it by running the following snippet ([that i took directly from the php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)) on the directory that you are uploading your files to:

```
<?php
$filename = 'test.txt';
if (is_writable($filename)) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}
?>
```